# Why do most Android applications place the navigation bar icon (hamburger menu icon) inside the search bar?

Tags: android, search, contextual-menu, hamburger, sidemenu

Apps like Play store and several other do this. They seem deeply flawed in their design. Since the hamburger menu has nothing to do with search, why is it designed in such a way?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this isn't a great reason, but the Material Design Spec considers the top app bar to be a [single component](https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-top.html#anatomy). As in "all the navigation interactions" happen in that area.

And... Google wants search to be the first and primary means of navigation so they're focusing the user's interactions there first. The message is sort of, "if a search doesn't give you what you need, this other stuff is here too."

I find it interesting that there isn't a hard answer for this question though even at Google. The Play Store functions as you described, but Gmail, Google News, and Google Home don't.

Answer (score 0):

Well, The reason why Hamburger menu and search are unified into a single component is that Hamburger Menu in a way is a form of simplified search grouped into categories. In case a person wants to perform a more specific search he/she could use the search bar to type in their keywords.

Hope this helps!!